# Issue while using generic

Tags: java, generics

I have below Genric class which is being used to set any custom data type

```java
        public class NotificationData<E> {
            private E element;
            public E getElement() {
                return element;
            }
```

Below Notification task interface which is showing a compile time error -

> T cannot be resolved to a type. I add "" in front of the method it does resolve error but creating issue for other classes which are using this interface.

```java
public interface NotificationTask {
             void execute(NotificationData<T> taskData);
            // --other methods
}
```

Below class implements its but showing error

> Name clash: The method execute(NotificationData) of type
>   AbstractEmailNotificationTask has the same erasure as
>   execute(NotificationData) of type NotificationTask but does not
>   override it

and prepareEmailTemplate show following error-

> The method prepareEmailTemplate(NotificationData) from the type
>   AbstractEmailNotificationTask refers to the missing type T

```java
public abstract class AbstractEmailNotificationTask implements NotificationTask{
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AbstractEmailNotificationTask.class);
    private boolean  flag;

    public <T> void execute(NotificationData<?> taskData) {
        try {
            String content=prepareEmailTemplate(taskData);
            setTaskExceuted(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug (e.getMessage (),e);
            setTaskExceuted(false);
        }
    }
    abstract protected  String prepareEmailTemplate(NotificationData<T> taskData) throws TaskExecutionException;
}



public class AddressUpdateEmailNotification extends AbstractEmailNotificationTask {
            public AddressUpdateEmailNotification() {
            }

            @Override
            protected  String prepareEmailTemplate(NotificationData<CustomerAddress> taskData) {
                CustomerAddress customerAddress= taskData.getElement();
                return customerAddress.getCity() +":"+customerAddress.getState().getStateName();
            }

        }
```

Above is actual class which will implement prepareEmail template. In this class I am passing CustomerAddress but in other Classes which are extending AbstractEmailNotificationTask, I have to pass other object. I want to use generic but facing these issues.

Comment: Why it is marked -1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface is not generic, thus the methods inside it are not recognized with the generic type (and cannot be resolved to one). Simply make it generic:

```
public interface NotificationTask<T> {
    void execute(NotificationData<T> taskData);
    // --other methods
}
```

Comment: I tried this and in this case I will have add "T" in all the classes which are implementing this interface and then abstract class and then then concrete class.

Comment: Now my concrete class is asking to type cast  at  taskData.getElement();

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing with generics. You have to implement it everywhere, otherwise it's not really generic. Please provide a code sample for the error you're getting

Comment: Thanks Ori, I am making changes , will post result.

Comment: I have resolved it and my test cases is working fine.